# Remove duplicates from output by using SQL

Tags: python, mysql, duplicates, web-crawler

In my initial step I crawled certain data like price, header and deeplink from a webpage, which I did successfully. Afterwards, I managed it to store into the database.

But the issus is that it also delivers a lot of duplicates that I would like to delete in the database.

And it seems that I´m running into walls when trying to delete the duplicates. Can someone help me out? What kind of SQL query do I have to use in order to delete the duplicates ones.

Any feedback is appreciated:)

Here is the code:

```
hallo = soup.find_all("article", {"class": "activity-card activity-card-horizontal "})

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect\
        (host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd ="", db = "output")
except:
    print("No connection to Server")
    sys.exit(0)

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("DELETE from prices_crawled where LocationID=" + str(location_ID) + " and PartnerID=" + str(partner_ID))
connection.commit()

for item in hallo:
    headers = item.find_all("h3", {"class": "activity-"})
    for header in headers:
        header_final = header.text.strip()

    prices = item.find_all("span", {"class": "price"})
    for price in prices:
        price_final = price.text.strip()[2:]

    deeplinks = item.find_all("a", {"class": "title"})
    for t in set(t.get("href") for t in deeplinks):
        deeplink_final = t

    Language = "Englisch"

    print("Header: " + header_final + " | " + "Price: " + str(price_final) + " | " + "Deeplink: " + deeplink_final + " | " + "PartnerID: " + str(partner_ID) + " | " + "LocationID: " + str(location_ID)+ " | " + "Language: " + Language)

    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO prices_crawled (price_id, Header, Price, Deeplink, PartnerID, LocationID, Language) \
            VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''', ['None'] + [header_final] + [price_final] + [deeplink_final] + [partner_ID] + [location_ID] + [Language])

    connection.commit()


cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: perhaps the easiest approach is to issue a query with `distinct` and copy the result to a new table. After that change the configuration of your table and create a primary key that blocks the creation of duplicates if you don't have other means to prevent this in your code (sorting the scraped data might already help find duplicates).

Comment: you could use unique constraints  and use `insert .... on duplicate update|Ignore`

Comment: @Marged: Thanks for your feedback but I do not get it properly. Could you elaborate more, if possible. How do I start the query with distinct? Thanks for your feedback and sorry if I getting on your nerves but I´m still a beginner